# Conditional Add to cart text on WooCommerce Single Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a code that would show different add to cart text on products that are part of category called "call".

My code so far is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    
 
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_product_category( 'call' ) ) {
        return __( 'Contact us', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    else {
        return __( 'Add to Basket', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Seems like I'm doing something wrong since Single product page shows without half of the content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is_product_category does not exist.  Use `get_category_ids` and replace $cat_id with the category id you want.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    $cat_id = 16;

    $product->get_category_ids();
    if ( in_array( $cat_id, $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
        return __( 'Contact us', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    else {
        return __( 'Add to Basket', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I must say I found this is_product_category condition tag on Woocomemrce page.

Comment: **is_product_category** condition tag on Woocomemrce page [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/). How come this condition doesn't work and on the other hand  **is_type** is working?

Comment: is_product_category() is a conditional tag that you use in a page template.  It's not a product function, it's similar to using a tag like is_home()

Comment: Got it. Thank you. By the way is it possible to add custom link on this C”ontact us” button?

Comment: Anything is possible :)  Ask a new question and I can help.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027614/custom-link-on-woocommerce-single-product-page-buy-button [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027614/custom-link-on-woocommerce-single-product-page-buy-button)