# Replace Add to cart button on Woocommerce Single Product Pages for a product category

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to add a custom link button that leads to Contact page - within first **if** condition that displays "Contact us" text with custom URL on the button instead of "Add to Basket" button.

How to do that? This is my code so far. It shows custom button text for each product which is part of category "64". That's exactly what I want. But how to add that button changes function from cart button to custom link button? Im figuring If have to change this cart buttons function. How?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    $cat_id = 64;

    $product->get_category_ids();
    if ( in_array( $cat_id, $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
        return __( 'Contact us', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    else {
        return __( 'Add to Basket', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is not working? What is expected? btw why not edit the single product page ( most likely single.php ) and add the button there? why use filter?

Comment: @cjmling I have only 10 products so it is not a big burden on server. This way I am avoiding possible update reset.

Comment: Instead of buy button that drops product into cart id like to have button with custom link

Answer (score 8):

For your product category ID 64, the following code will replace add to cart button by a custom button in single product pages and by a linked button to the product on archives pages:

```
// The custom replacement button function
function custom_product_button(){
    // HERE your custom button text and link
    $button_text = __( "Custom text", "woocommerce" );
    $button_link = '#';
    
    // Display button
    echo '<a class="button" href="'.$button_link.'">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}

// Replacing the single product button add to cart by a custom button for a specific product category
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    
    // Only for product category ID 64
    if( has_term( '64', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){

        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_product_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages for as specific product category
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Only for product category ID 64
    if( has_term( '64', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }

    return $button;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: LoicTheAztec, thank you. But seems like code is doing nothing. I'm inspecting it trying to figure out what is missing.

Comment: @Wed I have retested my code on different installations and it works. It works as well in all Woocommerce versions since version 3 (not tested version before 3). So the problem can come from your theme (that make changes in woocommerce hooks), from some plugins or from customizations that you have maid… You have also to be sure that the product category that you are targeting is ID 64…

Comment: im rechecking the rest of functions.php to see if something is conflicting.

Comment: Great answer! It gets the job done. Not only it changes buttons on product archive page but also single product page.

Answer (score 0):

**Add filter priority in hooks**

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text',50 );

Comment: Its not justa text. I want to add a function to replace buy button into custom URL button