# Add linked buttons to variations of variable product In Woocommerce archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

In woocommerce, I'm building a website which sells vintage maps. I need to find a way to pass the product id and variation id from the woocommerce shop to the single product page for two separate variations using buttons without adding the product to the cart.

There are two product types, the original map (of which there is obviously only one) and digital prints which are infinite.

I've separated these by creating a variable product with attributes 'original' and 'digital prints'. there is one variation per attribute so that much is pretty simple.

The company want these two options ('original' and 'digital prints') to appear in the woocommerce shop front page as buttons.

The idea is that the 'original' button will only appear if the original is in  stock (again, simple to achieve).

**The problems start here:**

The idea is that when either of these buttons are pressed it won't add the product to the cart but will go to the appropriate single product page and there, based on the variation type, there will be a range of options to select whether the map is framed and mounted, if it's digital how large the print should be etc. etc. Once selected, the product can then be added to the cart using the add to cart button on the single product page.

What I can't seem to do at the moment is send the information to the single product page without adding it to the cart(!)

The code I'm currently using uses woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item and woocommerce_single_variation to overwrite default add to cart button and replace it with the following but obviously this is still adding the product to the cart. Looking at the code, it's verbose and obviously over complicating things but I'm stumped. the add to cart button needs to be replaced with something that simply moves to the single product page and takes the product id and variation id with it but I don;t know what. In theory you can serialise it into an array and send as $_GET attached to an anchor but apart from the potential security issues this could give rise to, it looks shoddy in the toolbar.

So, in summary. I need to find a way to pass the product id and variation id from the woocommerce shop to the single product page for two separate variations using buttons without adding the product to the cart. Any ideas?

Code below:

```
function mc_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
global $product;

$product_obj = new WC_Product_Factory();
$product = $product_obj->get_product($product);   

if ($product->product_type == 'variable'):
  $children   = $product->get_children( $args = '', $output = OBJECT ); 

  foreach ($children as $key=>$value) {

      $product_variatons = new WC_Product_Variation($value);

      if ( $product_variatons->exists() && $product_variatons->variation_is_visible() ) {
          $variations[$value] = $product_variatons->get_variation_attributes();

          foreach ($variations[$value] as $key=>$value) {
            $stock = $product_variatons->get_stock_quantity();
            $product_price = $product_variatons->regular_price;



            if($value=="original") {

              if($stock > 0) {
                echo "Price: £" . $product_price;

            ?>

              <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
                <?php

                ?>
                  <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Buy <?php //echo $value; ?></button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
              </div>

                <?php
                } else {
                  echo "";
                }

            } else {
                echo "Price: £" . $product_price;
                ?>
              <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
                  <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Buy <?php echo $value; ?></button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
              </div>
                <?php
            }
          ?>



          <?php
          }
      }
  }
endif;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable products with a specific attribute for variations in archives pages as shop, the following code will:

- Remove the default price range
- Remove add to cart
- Add 2 buttons with prices linked to product variations

> The buttons links will take the customer to the right preselected variation in the variable product.

You will need to define in the first function the product attribute that has `'original'` and `'digital-prints'` term values. You need to define in the 2nd function the product attribute term slugs.

For the prints, we display the min price with something like `Price from: $123.00`.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_custom_variable_products', 2 );
function loop_custom_variable_products() {
    global $product;

    // HERE define the product attribute (for 'original' and 'digital-prints' term values
    $attribute = 'type'; // <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====

    // Only variable products
    if ( $product->get_type() === 'variable' && $product->get_attribute($attribute) ) :
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 ); // Remove price
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 ); // remove add to cart
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_variations_custom_buttons_and_prices', 10 ); // Add prices with custom buttons
    endif;
}

function loop_variations_custom_buttons_and_prices() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_type() === 'variable' ) :

    // HERE define your targeted slugs for the defined product attribute
    $targeted_slugs = array('original', 'digital-prints'); // <====  <====  <====  <====

    $found_original = $found_a_print = false;
    $data = $url_var = [];

    $min_price_html = __("Price from: ") . strip_tags( wc_price( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ) ) );

    // Loop through product variations ids
    foreach ($product->get_children() as $variation_id ){

        // Get the WC_Product_Variation Object
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

        if ( $variation->is_type('variation') && $variation->variation_is_visible() && $variation->variation_is_active() ) {
            $stock_qty  = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
            $price_html = __("Price: "); strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ) ) );
            $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();

            // Loop through variation attributes
            foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $term_slug ) {
                if( $term_slug === $targeted_slugs[0] ) {
                    $data[$term_slug]['price'] = $price_html . strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ) ) );
                    $data[$term_slug]['stock'] = $stock_qty > 0 ? true : false;

                    $found_original = true;
                }
                if( $term_slug === $targeted_slugs[1] ) {
                    $data[$term_slug]['price'] = $min_price_html;
                    $data[$term_slug]['stock'] = true;

                    $targeted_attribute = $attribute;

                    $found_a_print = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if( $found_original && $found_a_print) {
            // If both are found we stop the main loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // Output prices and buttons
    foreach( $targeted_slugs as $slug ) {
        if( isset($data[$slug]) && $data[$slug]['stock'] ) {
            echo '<div class="variation-' . $slug . '">
                <div class="price" style="margin-bottom:14px;">' . $data[$slug]['price'] . '</div>';
            foreach( $attributes as $key => $value ){
                if( isset($targeted_attribute) && $targeted_attribute === $key ) {
                    $url_var[] = $key . '=' . $slug;
                } else {
                    $url_var[] = $key . '=null';
                }
            }
            $href = $product->get_permalink() . '?' . implode('&', $url_var);
            echo '<a href="'.$href.'" class="button">' . __ ("Buy") . ' ' . str_replace('-', ' ', $slug)  . '</a>
            </div>';
        }
    }
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Loic - I actually engineered a partial solution using an answer you gave to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027614/replace-add-to-cart-button-on-woocommerce-single-product-pages-for-a-product-cat but this is a lot neater and fills some of the (many) gaps in my own knowledge, so, cheers ;-)

Comment: Have now been through this with a fine tooth comb. There are a couple of bits where I don't get *why* they work. First off, how come $targeted_attribute = $attribute; only gets set in the second conditional yet still works in the first? Is this a side effect of the foreach loop? ie it takes the last set value if not defined elsewhere? Secondly, $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes(); is only set in the first foreach loop. I'd have thought that the scope of the loop would have meant having to set it again in the second but apparently not? No need to answer more just thinking aloud

Comment: @Stef Explanations: 1) As you didn't give the main attribute involved in your question I use `$targeted_attribute = $attribute;` to catch the attribute that is mainly involve… 2) The 2nd foreach loop based on `$attributes` allow to set the correct url variables to the buttons links.